# Adding varying string values to a List inside a dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have varying string values that I want to add to a key inside a dictionary.

```
What is the correct answer(key)
AnswerA(value)
AnswerB(value)
AnswerC(value)
```

I am doing this by using the split on a string(which happens in a loop).

```
string[] arr = l.ContentDescription.Split('|').ToArray();
Dictionary<string, List<string>> questions = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length - 1; i++)
{
    var arrB = arr[i + 1].Split('*').ToArray();
    //all theanswers should now be added to the list 
    questions.Add(arrB[0], new List<string>() { });
}
```

arr looks something like this

```
Choose the correct answer and submit|What is the correct answer*AnswerA*AnswerB*AnswerC
```

What is the best way of adding these answer values if they vary in length

Comment: Maybe `questions.Add(arrB[0],  arrB.Skip(1).ToList() );` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just skip the first element in your array (Linq):

```
questions.Add(arrB[0], arrB.Skip(1).ToList());
```

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comment, a quick solution is to use `Skip` like this:

```
questions.Add(arrB[0], arrB.Skip(1).ToList());
```

Here is how I would do it all in LINQ:

```
var questions =
    l.ContentDescription
    .Split('|')
    .Skip(1) //get rid of "Choose the correct answer and submit"
    .Select(x => x.Split('*'))
    .ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => x.Skip(1).ToList());
```